# WooCommerce email template is not showing when sending custom emails from functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

The emails sent by WooCommerce like "order completed" are sent using the woocommerce email template to style the email content.

I'm sending a custom email using the woocommerce_thankyou hook within functions.php, but i would also like to use the WooCommerce email template to make the email more presentable.

I have tried using the wc_mail() function which is described as "Used to send an email using the WooCommerce email templates." in the docs but it actually doesn't, at least for me it's just a usual blank email with a message.

This is the code I have tried

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_customer_email_after_payment', 10, 1 );
function send_customer_email_after_payment( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Only send the email if the payment method is "Direct Bank Transfer"
    if ( 'bacs' !== $order->get_payment_method() ) {
        return;
    }

    $to = $order->get_billing_email();
    $subject = 'Thank you for your order';
    $message = 'Hello World';

    // Use the WooCommerce email template
    wc_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
}
```

Comment: `wc_mail` is just a helper function to send email using WooCommerce mailer, but that doesn't mean it will bring the HTML template as well, You'll have to get the template other ways and store the HTML in `$message` and pass in in `wc_mail` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You Can Use Your Custom Template Or Copy Template Content From Woocommerce
or include it**

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails

```
ob_start(); 
include('thank-you-template-file.php');
$message = ob_get_clean();
wc_mail('xxx@example.com', 'Thank you', $message, "Content-Type: text/html");
```

Comment: Where would I have to put the included php file? Seems like it can't be loaded. My template files are in the /woocommerce/emails/ subfolder of the active Wordpress theme.